# Generalized (Gnedenko Kolmogorov) limit theorem for distribution with inverse cube law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d.:s with finite variance $\sigma^2$ (and zero mean, for simplicity), the central limit theorem tells us that the stochastic variable $S_n$, defined by $$S_n = (X_1+...+X_n)/\sqrt{n},$$ tends to the Gaussian $N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution, as $n \to \infty$.

There is a generalized limit theorem, due to Gnedenko and Kolmogorov, which deals with the case when the $X_i$ are i.i.d.:s with undefined variance (i.e. infinite), see e.g. the following wikipedia article on [Stable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) but also the book "Econophysics" by Stanley and Mantegna. Hence let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d.:s, drawn from a symmetric distribution around the origin, and with power law tails, such that the pdf $f$ satisfies $$f(x) \sim |x|^{-(1+\alpha)},$$
where $\alpha$ is a parameter. Clearly we must have $\alpha > 0$, in order for the distribution to be normalizable. Further, if $\alpha > 2$, the variance is finite, so the ordinary central limit theorem applies. Hence consider the case $\alpha \in (0,2]$. According to the generalized limit theorem, the stochastic variable $S_n$, defined by $$S_n = (X_1+...+X_n)/n^{1/\alpha},$$
tends to a Lévy $\alpha$-stable distribution, with stability parameter $\alpha$ (the skewness and location parameters are both zero due to the symmetry assumption), as $n \to \infty$.

My question concerns the specific case when $\alpha=2$ and whether the theorem actually applies in this case. Indeed, when $\alpha = 2$ the Lévy $\alpha$-stable distribution reduces to a Gaussian. The generalized limit theorem, as stated above, would therefore imply that if $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d.:s, either with finite variance or with inverse cube tails, then the stochastic variable $S_n$, defined by $$S_n = (X_1+...+X_n)/\sqrt{n},$$ tends to the Gaussian $N(0,\sigma^2)$, as $n \to \infty$. Is this correct, i.e. does the conclusion of the central limit theorem remain valid, even when the variance of the $X_i$ is undefined, provided they are drawn from a distribution with inverse cube tails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, let $S_n=n^{-1/2}\sum_1^n X_i$ where the $X_i$ are iid and $X_1$ is any symmetric random variable (for your specific question you can take $X_1$ to have pdf $f(x)= |x|^{-3}1_{\{|x|>1\}}$). I claim that $S_n$ won't converge in law to a Gaussian unless $X_1$ has a finite second moment.

For a random variable $Y$, let $\phi_{Y}(x)$ denote the characteristic function of $Y$. It's clear that $$\phi_{S_n}(x) = \phi_{X_1}(n^{-1/2}x)^n.$$

Suppose $S_n$ converged in law to some random variable $Z \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Then the characteristic functions converge pointwise, i.e. $\phi_{S_n}(x) \to \phi_Z(x)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Thus $\phi_{X_1}(n^{-1/2})^n = \phi_{S_n}(1) \to \phi_Z(1) = e^{-\sigma^2/2}>0$. Also, since $X_1$ was assumed to be symmetric, it follows that $\phi_{X_1}$ is real valued. Thus $\phi_{X_1}(n^{-1/2}) > 1-C/n$ for some constant $C$.

Thus $\Bbb E[\cos(n^{-1/2}X_1)] = \phi_{X_1}(n^{-1/2})>1-C/n.$ Thus by Fatou's lemma and the fact that $x^2 = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(tx)}{t^2/2}$, we find that $$\Bbb E[X_1^2] \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \Bbb E \bigg[ \frac{1-\cos(n^{-1/2}X_1)}{\frac12 n^{-1}} \bigg] \leq 2 C. $$

Thus $X_1$ has finite second moment.

**Edit:** Actually the wikipedia article you linked [gives a direct proof of the fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution#A_generalized_central_limit_theorem) that in the case of $|x|^{-3}$ tails, the partial sums normalized by $\sqrt{n \log n}$ converges to a Gaussian distribution. Notice the additional $\sqrt{\log n}$ factor. You will need to scroll down a little bit in that link.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I find it very curious that the convergence fails unless the $X_i$ have finite second moments. In both the book and the wiki page I cite they seem to allow $\alpha=2$ in the generalized central limit theorem.

Comment: @ÉtienneBézout Sure no problem. Also, see my edit. Also there was a mistake which is now fixed, but I needed to make slightly stronger assumptions on $X_1$.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now that it is mentioned in the wiki article. It was however not mentioned in the "Econophysics" book, which was the original source of my question. Still, the whole thing seems counterintuitive to me. For $\alpha < 2$, $S_n/n^{1/\alpha}$ converges to a certain distribution, but at $\alpha=2$, suddenly we need an additional factor of $1/\sqrt{\log n}$ for the convergence to work.